# Error: this.getToken is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, ng-show

I have a factory that returns 3 functions: `setToken`, `getToken`, `isAuthenticated`. The first two functions are predefined, and the last one calls the `getToken` function, using `this.getToken`.

When injecting the factory into the controller, I then call the third function (`isAuthenticated()`), using `ng-show`. I get the following error in my console:

> Error: this.getToken is not a function
>   .isAuthenticated@http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/authtoken.js:22:16

Can anybody help me with what I'm doing wrong?

**The factory:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('psJwtApp').factory('authToken', function($window) {
  //define storage
  var storage = $window.localStorage;
  var cachedToken;

  // Public API here
  return {
    setToken: function(token) {
      cachedToken = token;
      storage.setItem('userToken', token);
    },
    getToken: function() {
      if (!cachedToken) {
        cachedToken = storage.getItem('userToken');
      }
      return cachedToken;
    },
    isAuthenticated: function() {
      //return true if we get something from getToken
      return !!this.getToken();
    }
  };

});
```

**The Controller:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('psJwtApp').controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope, authToken) {
    $scope.isAuthenticated = authToken.isAuthenticated;
});
```

**The View:**

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="main">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-hide="isAuthenticated()" ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-show="isAuthenticated()" ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="logout">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

If you feel that anything is missing or need more information, please ask and I'll add it to the question.

Comment: try caching this; 
var me = this;
return !!me.getToken();

Comment: still returns the same error - Error: me.getToken is not a function

Comment: where did u declare the var me = this; ?

Comment: inside the isAuthenticated function

Comment: declare along with the other var

Comment: even declaring it outside the function did not work. The anwser below did though. Thanks for the help

Comment: yeap he got it right, you might find use of the var me = this; some other time maybe :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getToken` is a static method of the object you are exposing in the factory, so you can't refer to it with `this`. You can however do something like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('psJwtApp').factory('authToken', function($window) {
  //define storage
  var storage = $window.localStorage;
  var cachedToken;

  var setToken = function(token) {
    cachedToken = token;
    storage.setItem('userToken', token);
  };
  var getToken = function() {
    if (!cachedToken) {
      cachedToken = storage.getItem('userToken');
    }
    return cachedToken;
  };
  var isAuthenticated = function() {
    //return true if we get something from getToken
    return !!getToken();
  };

  // Public API here
  return {
    setToken: setToken,
    getToken: getToken,
    isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated
  };

});
```